# Does Cache-Control: no-cache="Set-Cookie, Set-Cookie2" actually prevent caching cookies?

Tags: cookies, session-management

[This OWASP recommendation](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Session_Management_Cheat_Sheet.html#web-content-caching) says:

> it is highly recommended to use the Cache-Control: no-cache="Set-Cookie, Set-Cookie2" directive, to allow web clients to cache everything except the session ID

But [the mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control) say

> The no-cache response directive indicates that the response can be stored in caches, but the response must be validated with the origin server before each reuse, even when the cache is disconnected from the origin server.

So no-cache can't actually prevent the caching of session cookies, can it?

Answer (score 0):

I've checked [RFC2068](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2068)

```
cache-response-directive =
                          | "no-cache" [ "=" <"> 1#field-name <"> ]
```

> When a directive appears without any 1#field-name parameter, the
> directive applies to the entire request or response. When such a
> directive appears with a 1#field-name parameter, it applies only to
> the named field or fields, and not to the rest of the request or
> response.  This mechanism supports extensibility; implementations of
> future versions of the HTTP protocol may apply these directives to
> header fields not defined in HTTP/1.1.

So the OWASP recommendation (https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Session_Management_Cheat_Sheet.html#web-content-caching) you have mentioned is about caching Set-cookie directive, but the Mozilla documentation (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control) is about caching generally and for all response.

So if you set `Cache-Control: no-cache="Set-Cookie"`, the response can be cached, but without Set-Cookie headers. I found a similar discussion [here](http://www.squid-cache.org/mail-archive/squid-dev/199704/0016.html).

But I did a test on my application, when there was a header `Cache-Control: no-cache` my session ID cookie was cached. I can find it in Firefox browser using URL `about:cache` to check cache details.

[image]

and in cache file:

[image]

But when setting `Cache-Control: no-cache="Set-Cookie"` there was no difference in my browser cache. I also found session ID cookie.

[image]

Generally `no-cache` directive when it is set in the response header `Cache-Control: no-cache`  does not mean "don't cache". As you can see in mentioned documentation

> no-cache allows caches to store a response but requires them to revalidate it before reuse. If the sense of "don't cache" that you want is actually "don't store", then no-store is the directive to use.

I suppose that this is the reason for such a browser behavior. But I'm not sure on this topic, if I'm wrong please correct me.

Comment: So it seems that the OWASP recommendation is wrong then, right? It's cached either way?